# sql логическая сортировка

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, подзапрос

Имеется БД в MS SQL Server, Таблица WorkitemsCache содержит жизненный цикл талона (тикета), который разработчик доводил до логического завершения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Требуется вернуть список строк, которые отрываются более чем на 5 мин от предыдущей строки с таким же TicketId.
Планирую это реализовать с помощью подзапроса и ORDER BY, но выхода пока не нашел.
Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь.

Comment: А в чём именно сложность?

Comment: Честно говоря, не знаю как правильно выставить логическое условие, которое позволит выполнить поставленную задачу(

Comment: сложность в выборе оператора сортировки даты

Comment: Даты спокойно сравниваются, сортируются и т.д. Чтобы 5 минут прибавить можете использовать `DATEDIFF(minute, дата1, дата2) > 5`

Comment: ... а значение из предыдущей строки достанет функция LAG()

Answer (score 1):

Если так:

```
declare
    @t table (Ticket int, DT datetime)

declare
    @dt datetime=getdate()
insert into @t 
select 1, @dt
union all
select 1, dateadd(minute, 1, @dt)
union all
select 1, dateadd(minute, 7, @dt)
union all
select 1, dateadd(minute, 10, @dt)
union all
select 1, dateadd(minute, 37, @dt)
union all
select 2, @dt
union all
select 2, dateadd(minute, 2, @dt)
union all
select 2, dateadd(minute, 10, @dt)
union all
select 2, dateadd(minute, 25, @dt)
union all
select 2, dateadd(minute, 27, @dt)


select *, datediff (minute, PrevDT, DT) from (
    select *, LAG (DT, 1 )  over (PARTITION BY Ticket order by Ticket, DT) as PrevDT
    from @t
)t
where datediff (minute, PrevDT, DT)>5
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]